# Something wrong with end property of React Native Big Calendar

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a calendar of event using react-native-big-calendar

when i believe it's suppose to work with both start and end time, but somehow it's not work when i uncomment the end property

here are the codes:

```
const events = [
  {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: new Date(2020, 5, 20, 10, 0),
    // end: new Date(2020, 5, 20, 22, 30),
  },
  {
    title: 'Coffee break',
    start: new Date(2020, 1, 14, 15, 45),
    // end: new Date(2020, 1, 14, 16, 30),
  },
  {
    title: 'Repair my car',
    start: new Date(2020, 5, 20, 7, 45),
    // end: new Date(2020, 5, 20, 13, 30),
  },
]
class BookingListScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }
  render() {
    console.log('logged by phuognn start: ', new Date(2020, 5, 20, 10, 0));
    console.log('logged by phuognn end: ',new Date(2020, 5, 20, 22, 30));  
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Calendar

          height={Dimensions.get('window').height}
          style={styles.calendar}
          events={events}
          height={600}
          eventCellStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
        />
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

if I uncomment the end property of events, the calendar show no event.
Wonder why?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `end` property is required on the type `BaseEvent`. So you must specify it!

`node_modules\react-native-big-calendar\build\interfaces.d.ts`

```js
export interface BaseEvent {
    start: Date;
    end: Date;
    title: string;
}
```

If what you're looking for is an event which lasts all day, use event's time.

```js
const events = [
  {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: new Date(2020, 1, 11, 0, 0),
    end: new Date(2020, 1, 12, 0, 0),
  }
]
```